# advice about how I can combine 2 Handlebars templates that both use the same data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I'm currently learning how to template using Handlebars and would like some advice about how I would combine the following 2 templates into 1 and update my script so each button still displays the correct set of values?

**Templates**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="infoTemp">
    {{#each films}}
    <li>
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <p>{{{description}}}</p>        
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="additionalInfoTemp">
    {{#each films}}
    <li>
        <h1>{{id}}</h1>
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <p>{{{description}}}</p>
        <small>{{released}}</small>        
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

**JS**

```
// Dummy data
data = {
    "films": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
        "description": "Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.",
        "released": "2012-09-17 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "The Godfather",
        "description": "The aging <b>patriarch of an organized</b> crime dynasty transfers control of his clandestine empire to his reluctant son.",
        "released": "2012-09-17 00:00:00"
    }
    ]
}

var $info = $('#info');
var source;
//Grab contents of template

function templateData(id){
    if( id == 'add1' ){
        source = $("#infoTemp").html();
    } else {
        source = $("#additionalInfoTemp").html();
    }

    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    $info.append(template(data));
}

//Grab the container div and insert the templated data in


$('button').on('click', function(e){
    var thisData = $(this).data('id');

    $info.html('');

    templateData(thisData);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**JS Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/2TpJh/2/

​

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the existence of each of the variables and render the `h1` and `released` only if they exist:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="additionalInfoTemp">
    {{#each films}}
    <li>
        {{#id}}<h1>{{.}}</h1>{{/id}}
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <p>{{{description}}}</p>
        {{#released}}<small>{{.}}</small>{{/released}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: hey, the problem is the data will be identical on both occasions meaning that each variable will exist?

Comment: Those are effectively separate templates then. If you want to reuse the template, you can create a different view of the data that doesn't provide the "id" or "released".